# every element of list is True boolean

Tags: python

I know that

```
all(map(compare,new_subjects.values()))==True
```

would tell me if every element of the list is True.  However, how do I tell whether every element except for one of them is True?

Comment: I don't know python very well, but why can't you just scan the list and count how many elements are true, then if you find only one the answer is "yes", otherwise is "no". These are functions you usually write in the first 2-3 months of learning programming basics.

Even if I don't know Python, I'm pretty sure there's no "whether every element except for one of them is True" automagic function...

Comment: @Giacomo there's no function, but it is a one liner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
values = map(compare, new_subjects.values())
len([x for x in values if x]) == len(values) - 1
```

Basically, you filter the list for true values and compare the length of that list to the original to see if it's one less.

Comment: Well really a powerful language, but that touch of magic makes stuff less readable. At a first sight, the code tells very little on what it actually does. For this very problem, a simple loop with a counter (in C, for example) is far more understandable even for a VB, or Pascal programmer. The stuff at line 2 of your code tells me nothing, it seems like automagic and tricky. I'll dig into python, I'm curious when languages get tricky.

Comment: @Giacomo I'd probably pair it with a comment, in practice. List comprehensions look a bit wonky to outsiders, but they're quite nice once you get used to them.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  I'm trying to understand this notation as well.

Comment: @Glassjawed see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions for help on list comprehensions. You could also use `filter`, but that would make less sense IMO.

Comment: @Rafe, it really depends. `filter` makes a lot of sense when you come from a functional background.

Comment: @Mike I'm more speaking to this particular use, where it would be `len(filter(lambda x: x, values))`. That lambda might be a bit confusing. In the general case, you're right, it depends.

Comment: `filter(None, values)` does the same ;p

Comment: @Jochen that would be even more confusing to many, TBH, but nice trick.

Comment: @Giacomo: List comprehensions are a powerful feature and if you learn any Python at all, you'll learn about them soon. I will *not* restrict the features used in my code to what exists in C just so C programmers can understand it. When you try to read code in language L, you *have* to know some L.

Comment: @delnan: you're definitely right. But like in English there's a "common English" which is in a way poorer than Shakespeare's one, but lets you talk with an Indian, a French or an Eskimo, in the programming community there's a "common Coding" :D that is not "standardized", but in fact lets people understand your code. My PHP code (when I write PHP) is understandable to anybody, and I don't use the tricky-scripty-nasty-sweetie features I know like ${${WHATTHEHELL}{WHAT}${$$${THEHELL}}} :)
So len([x for x in values if x]) may be cool (and solves the issue), but as to readability it's dump.

Comment: But list comprehensions are simple. They're well-understood by everyone who learned about them and used them for a few days. As I said before, they're not an obscure feature, they're perfectly common in perfectly readable Python code. And no, your code (PHP or otherwise) it not understandable to anyone. Propably not even to all programmers if they're used to completely different languages. And it doesn't have to. Apart from that, would you refrain from using e.g. string interpolation for this aim?

Answer (score 7):

If you mean is actually `True` and not evaluates to True, you can just count them?

```
>>> L1 = [True]*5
>>> L1
[True, True, True, True, True]
>>> L2 = [True]*5 + [False]*2
>>> L2
[True, True, True, True, True, False, False]
>>> L1.count(False)
0
>>> L2.count(False)
2
>>>
```

checking for only a single False:

```
>>> def there_can_be_only_one(L):
...     return L.count(False) == 1
... 
>>> there_can_be_only_one(L1)
False
>>> there_can_be_only_one(L2)
False
>>> L3 = [ True, True, False ]
>>> there_can_be_only_one(L3)
True
>>>
```

**edit:** This actually answer your question better:

```
>>> def there_must_be_only_one(L):
...     return L.count(True) == len(L)-1
... 
>>> there_must_be_only_one(L3)
True
>>> there_must_be_only_one(L2)
False
>>> there_must_be_only_one(L1)
False
```

Answer (score 4):

Count how many are not True:

```
values = (compare(val) for val in new_subjects.itervalues())
if sum(1 for x in values if not x) == 1: # just one
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the compare function returns a boolean vaue, and knowing that True/False become 1/0 in an integer context you can do:

```
values = new_subjects.values()
sum(compare(v) for v in values) == len(values) -1
```